# I restarted my computer, and now all i see is a black screen with a typing line

Tags: boot

My computer has three internal hard drives, one SSD (with Ubuntu installed on it), and two HDD's. I had just finished formatting the two HDD's, and all was well. I had not touched to SSD at all. I restarted my computer after they'd finished. My computer went through the regular "press this for bios" screen, and then it goes black, with a tiny white horizontal line blinking, like i should be able to type.

I can't. Nothing on my keyboard seems to do anything, and I'm kinda lost on what to do. I only switched my main desktop two days ago, so
im pretty new to this. I posted a picture to Reddit for context here https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/oulnef/i_just_restarted_my_pc_and_now_all_i_see_is_this/

Comment: It is possible the bootloader may have been installed to a hard drive which has been erased, even though the operating system was installed to the SSD. Sometimes, the Ubuntu installer will choose a different disk which appears higher in the BIOS boot order, or an existing EFI System Partition to install the bootloader to – this is most likely the case if you have Windows or another operating system installed on one of those hard drives. You will most likely need to reinstall the bootloader from a newly created live DVD or USB drive. If this is the case, don't worry – it can be reinstalled.

Comment: Thank-you for this! I had a good look through and tried many of the suggestions, however most of these assume that i have at least some sort of access to the login screen, or that i can use shortcuts. All i have access to at the moment is the BIOS. It's as if Linux has completely uninstalled itself.

Comment: @galexite Do you know if reinstalling from a flash drive will wipe my system? What will i lose? Do i keep drivers i installed? Thanks!

Comment: Reinstalling the bootloader will not clear the contents of the drive. Reinstalling the operating system, however, will.

Comment: I recommend you use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair by installing it on a live DVD or USB system, and following the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who helped me! I managed to fix the issue in the end. For some reason, my BIOS had changed to boot from one of the HDD's instead of the SSD. To fix this, i simply changed the boot order to start from the SSD instead. Hope anyone having the same issue in the future finds this helpful!